# Prove that a graph has a cycle of length no more than $14$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

A graph contains $2016$ vertices, its chromatic number is $5$, prove that this graph has a cycle of length $\leq 14$.

Where do I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the chromatic number is 5, the graph must contain a subgraph $H$ of minimum degree at least 4. Suppose for contradiction that the graph has no cycles of length at most 14.

Consider a vertex $v$ of $H$ and consider the subgraph $J$ formed by vertices at distance at most 7 from $v$. Then $J$ is acyclic. So if $n_i$ is the set of vertices at distance $i$ from $v$, you can see that $n_1 \geq 4$ and $n_2 \geq 12$, $n_3 \geq 36$ etc. Adding these numbers up to level 7 should give a number greater than 2016, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I didn't quite understand it, can you please elaborate? Why did you say that H has minimum degree of 4? What does it have to do with anything? Why is J acyclic? And how did you compute those the lower bounds for $n_i$?

Answer (score 0):

Helping to unpack Aravind's answer.

A graph $H$ with chromatic number $\chi(H)=k$ is called $k$-*critical* if, for every vertex $v\in V(H)$, the graph $H-v$ has chromatic number $k-1$. It's hopefully easy to see that your $G$ has a $5$-critical subgraph $H$.

Suppose a $k$-critical subgraph $H$ of a graph $G$ with $\chi(G)=k$ has a vertex $v$ of degree strictly less than $k-1$. Since $H$ is $k$-critical, we know $\chi(H-v)=k-1$. But since $d_H(v)<k-1$, we can color $H-v$ using at most $k-1$ colors, and then since $v$ has less than $k-1$ neighbors in $H$, one of the $k-1$ colors is not used for any neighbor of $v$. Use this color for $v$, and you have a proper $k-1$-coloring of $H$, contradicting the $k$-criticality of $H$.

So, you may consider a subgraph $H$ of your $G$ for which $\delta(H)\ge4$. Let $J$ be the induced subgraph of $H$ formed by vertices $u$ for which $H$ has a $uv$-path of length at most $7$.

Now suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $G$ has no cycles of length at most $14$. Then $J$ should certainly be acyclic, for if $u$ and $w$ are neighbors on a cycle in $J$, then there are in $J$ a $uv$-path of length at most $7$ and a $uw$-path of length at most $7$, giving a cycle of length at most $14$, a contradiction to our assumption about $G$'s cycles.

This means no two of the vertices at distance $i$ from $v$ can share a neighbor, so since $\delta(H)\ge4$, you know that at distance $i$ from $v$, you see at least $3$ new vertices *per vertex* that is at distance $i-1$ from $v$.

So $v$ has at least $4$ neighbors, each of those has at least $3$ new and distinct neighbors (which are the list at distance $2$ from $v$), so there are at least $$\sum_{i=0}^{6}4\cdot3^i=4372$$ vertices in acyclic $J$ distinct from $v$.

But then $J$ has to be bigger than you've allowed $G$ to be, so this contradicts the condition on the order of $G$. We conclude our supposition that $G$ has no cycles of length at most $14$ must be false.